# Angular material : How to hide mat-tab-header when mat-tab is hidden?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-tab

i have a basic `mat-tab-group` with 2 `mat-tab` nested inside it. Both `mat-tab` have a `[hidden]` input attribute, determined by a boolean value that changes in my code. It is working like a charm for the `mat-tab` themselves, meaning that when the `[hidden]` inputed expression value is false, tabs are not displayed.
Problem is, `mat-tab-header` is still visible, and leads to the possibility of clicking and go to an empty tab.

Is there any solution that can bind associated `mat-tab-header` visibility with his related `mat-tab`?

I Cannot use `ngIf` because i do need the tabs to be present on the DOM for data processing and lifecycles reasons.

Generic situation :

```
     <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab [hidden]="isFirstTabHidden" [label]="tab1">
          {{1st Tab}}
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab [hidden]="isSecondTabHidden"
                 [label]="tab2">
         {{Second Tab}}
        </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: please share the minimal reproducible example where this issue occours, I tried it, but hidden did not work [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hjczmr?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts)